# excel formula, subtract date to get # of days

Tags: microsoft-excel

currently I am trying to subtract two dates and get the number of dates between.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

How can I convert these from Text to get a proper number difference?

Comment: The same question has already been asked on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056051/4721734

Answer (score 1):

In **C1** enter:

```
=DATE(LEFT(B1,4),MID(B1,5,2),RIGHT(B1,2))-DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2))
```

[image]